# How to change color of mysql data?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, colors

This is my code :

```
echo "<td>".$row['Alpha']."</td>";

echo "<td>".$row['Beta']."</td>";
```

I want to show if `$row['Alpha'] is <=100` , then color that value with red ,else if `$row['Alpha']>100` then to color that value with black .And same for `$row['Beta']`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is hard to tell what is your problem. Do you need help with the SQL, php or html css part? Please clarify your question.

Comment: use css file for designing and coloring the html elements...
Like `echo '<td style="color:red">'.$row['Alpha'].'</td>'; `

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
echo "<td style='color:" . ($row['Alpha'] <= 100 ? "red;": "black;") . "'>" . $row['Alpha'] . "</td>";
echo "<td style='color:" . ($row['Beta'] <= 100 ? "red;": "black;") . "'>" . $row['Beta'] . "</td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

then

```
if($row['Alpha'] <= 100) {
  echo '<span style="color:red;">'.$row['Alpha'].'</span>';
}
else{
  echo '<span style="color:black;">'.$row['Alpha'].'</span>';
}
// so on for beta
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code:

```
<?php
   //connection to the database and execution of the query
   if($row['Alpha'] <= 100){
      echo "<td style=\"color:#F00\>" . $row['Alpha'] . "</td>";
   }
   else{ 
      echo "<td style=\"color:#000\">" . $row['Alpha'] . "</td>";
   }
   if($row['Beta'] <= 100){
      echo "<td style=\"color:#F00\>" . $row['Beta'] . "</td>";
   }
   else{ 
      echo "<td style=\"color:#000\">" . $row['Beta'] . "</td>";
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($row['Alpha'] <= 100) $color = 'red';
if ($row['Alpha'] > 100) $color = 'black';
if ($row['Beta'] <= 100) $color = 'red';
if ($row['Beta'] > 100) $color = 'black';

echo "<span style=\"color: $color;\">This text is colored.</span>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like this?

```
if ($row['Alpha'] <= 100)
    echo "<td style='color:red;'>".$row['Alpha']."</td>";
else
    echo "<td style='color:black;'>".$row['Alpha']."</td>";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<style type="text/css">
.warning {
    color: red;
}
</style>

echo '<td' . ($row['x'] <= 100? ' class="warning"': '') . '>' . htmlentities($row['x']) . '</td>';
```